# print to wifi direct without losing my internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking

My experience seems to be that when I connect to wifi direct (laser printer is wifi direct device), that my internet connection drops.

Can I keep both connections up?

(Using surface 4 pro / win 10, the printer is networked, but my internet comes from a different connection)

Answer (score 0):

If ur internet and wifi are on different networks - IE 192.168.1.xxx vs 192.168.100.xxx then that may be the issue. If I plug a connector into my laptop the wifi will stop - even though it is the same network.